# How should tags be chosen?

Tags: discussion

When I ask a question and choose/define tags I follow the logic of keywords, but tags on this site are mostly used for categories that people want to follow or ignore.

I feel that this is not quite the same thing.

For example, in my newest question on the meaning of "zwie" in the word "Zwielicht", I finally chose as tags "meaning" and "wortteil"  (=part of word).

But I feel that the question is somewhere in the middle between meaning and etymology and I am not sure that it is really of interest whether a question refers to a "single-word", "part of word" or "phrase".

So, which kind of tags are useful?

Comment: I think this needs discussion. I find it hard to draw the line between `translation`, `single-word-request`, `meaning` and `etymology`.

Answer (score 2):

As a partial reply to the comment by Tim, I want to say that *as a user, not an asker*, I find etymology, translation and meaning useful insofar as I am interested in these tags and would favourite them and while I agree that meaning has an overlap with the other two it is not a subset.

For example, for the phrase "Du kannst mich mal" (attention, vulgar phrase), asking for the etymology, a translation and the meaning are clearly not the same thing.

On the other hand, the point of "single-word-request" seems to be simply to make the question more precise which is a strange use of tags. Who would want to follow questions that ask for a single word equivalent of "not thirsty anymore" but not want to follow question that ask for the best translation of it?